Watershed tool is running, yet no raster appears in ArcGIS Pro
I am working to delineate watersheds in ArcGIS Pro and have my sinks filled, flow direction and flow accumulation done as well as selecting an outlet. When I run the watershed tool, it seems to run no problems but then the raster of the watershed doesn't always appear. I have some luck fixing this by rerunning the watershed tool over and over again, sometimes restarting ArcGIS Pro but I'm sure there is a larger issue causing this that I just don't know.
Any ideas what might be causing this?
Maybe it is an issue with the outlet selection.

Check if your outlet point sits on high flow accumulation cell, not next to it
